# Programmatically add key in web.config for application deployed in web farm

Tags: asp.net, .net, web-farm

How can I make the config.AppSettings.Add(key,value) to add new key on all boxes in a web farm Programmatically ?

Answer (score 2):

Here's some code to add or update a key:

```
Dim cfg As System.Configuration.Configuration = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(Configuration.ConfigurationUserLevel.None)

cfg.AppSettings.Settings.Remove(key) //Get rid of the existing value
cfg.AppSettings.Settings.Add(key, val)

cfg.Save(Configuration.ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified)
```

Comment: what about web farm scenario..this code will update config on one particular box only